# Синхронизация одинаковых частей разных файлов

Tags: ide

Подскажите, пожалуйста, инструменты или способ синхронизации частей файлов.
Проще всего объяснить смысл на задаче:

Есть мобильное приложение на jQuery Mobile который состоит из множества файлов у которых такое содержимое:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">

        =====>  Content     <=====

          <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

От страницы к странице меняется только контент, а верх и низ остаются одинаковыми.
Есть ли инструменты для того, чтобы если в одном файле изменился верх или низ - во все остальные файлы было внесено то же изменение?

---

## Дополнение

Окончательно определился как это все должно выглядеть:

- Это встроенное средство некой IDE
- Если в файле открытом в этой IDE происходит изменение связанных частей, то это изменение сразу отражается в других файлах, которые не открыты в данной IDE для редактирования
- Если файл открыт в IDE, то изменение отражается после того, как будет закрыто редактирование файла или файл сохранен

Существуют ли такие решения в какой-нибудь IDE ?

Comment: ну обычно это делают на шаблонах, которые затем потом подключают. Изменился шаблон - изменилось везде, чем такой подход не устраивает?

Comment: @BOPOH , html5 приложение может быть представлено как сайт или автономное мобильное приложение в обертке к примеру PhoneGap, а значит PHP и другие шаблонизаторы будут исключительно серверной частью. Весь клиентский код предпочтительно представлять в виде законченных файлов готовых к сборке в мобильное приложение или веб-сайт.

Comment: я это прекрасно понимаю, у нас игры под phonegap пишут и шаблонизатор активно применяется. Раньше, по крайней мере, применялся, я давно не писал под html, как сейчас у них дела не знаю

Comment: @BOPOH как результат хочется получить полностью автономное приложение способное работать без наличия интернета. Серверные шиблонизаторы задействовать не получится :(

Comment: так я не про серверные говорю, у того же jquery есть шаблонизатор ([пример с хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/91253/)) или [пример с jquerymobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/multipage-template.html), кроме того на js.ru есть статьи по этому поводу: [тыц](https://learn.javascript.ru/template-lodash) и [тыц](https://learn.javascript.ru/templates) и т.д.

Comment: Есть же клиентские шаблонизаторы..... `mustache` к примеру....вам стоит покопать в сторону клиентских шаблонизаторов))) не только на сервере они есть)) ....http://habrahabr.ru/post/219873/   15 штук ))

Comment: `gulp` или `grunt` в паре с кордовой неплохо пойдут + оставят простор в выборе шаблонизатора

Comment: Обновил ответ, как выглядит фича моей мечты :)